# Xcode device deployment coding error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

When i run my application in the IOS Simulator, everything works fine, including the logging in and signing up actions. Now, when I deploy the application onto my actual IOS device, everything runs accordingly, until I attempt those same login and sign up actions. The app force closes, however when re-opened, the user has still been logged in or signed up.

**here is the logic for my login**:

```
 @IBAction func Login(sender: AnyObject) {
       activityIND.hidden = false
       activityIND.startAnimating()

       var userName = usernameText.text
       var passWord = passwordText.text

       PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(userName, password: passWord) {
           (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
           if user != nil {
               dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                   self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginSucess", sender: self)
               }
           } else {
               self.activityIND.stopAnimating()

               if let message: AnyObject = error!.userInfo!["error"] {
                   self.message.text = "\(message)"
               }
          }
     }
}
```

**here is the logic for my sign up:**

```
  func processSignUp() {
       var userUsername = usernameTxt.text
       var userEmailAdress = emailTxt.text
       var userPassword = passwordTxt.text
       var confirmPassword = confirmTxt.text
       var yes = false
       var no = false




       //start activity indicator
       activityIndicator.hidden = false
       activityIndicator.startAnimating()

       //create new user
       var user = PFUser()
       user.username = userUsername
       user.email = userEmailAdress
       user.password = userPassword

       //ensure confirm password is equal to password
       if confirmPassword == userPassword {
           yes = true
       } else {
           let passAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Sign Up Failed", message: "Sorry, your passwords are not matching", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
           passAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
           self.presentViewController(passAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
           self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
       }; if userUsername == "" || userEmailAdress == "" || userPassword == "" || confirmPassword == "" {
           let blankAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Sign Up Failed", message: "Sorry, some fields are blank", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
           blankAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
           self.presentViewController(blankAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
           self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
       } else {
           no = true
       }; if yes && no {

       user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock { (
           success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
           if error == nil {

               dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                   self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToTab", sender: self)
               }
           } else {

               self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
               if let message: AnyObject = error!.userInfo!["error"] {
                   self.message.text = "\(message)"
               }
             }
          }
       }
   }
```

I doubt there is an issue with either of the logic because the processes both work, they just crash when i run it through my actual device. Now I do have about 22 warnings varying from misplaced views, unsupported configuartions, and ambiguous layouts however like i said despite these warnings the app runs fine and all my UI elements are placed how I desired them. What seems to be the issue?

Comment: "The app force closes" Also called a crash! And it leaves a crash log in the console. What does it say? On what line does it occur?

Comment: Uh huh. But you still didn't answer my question: what's the crash and where?

Comment: Uh huh, you have "about 22 warnings", fix them. Also run the analyzer and fix any complaints it finds. Good code has no warnings.

Comment: It leaves an error on the class declaration of the Appdelegate reading : `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x10)` @matt

Comment: thats the thing, I'm unsure of how to fix these frames and constraints without it breaking my UI.. theres a reason i put those constraints there, the suggested constraints weren't doing its part @zaph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saying

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
```

This suggests you think this code is running in a background thread so that you need to get out to the main thread. That is not an unreasonable assumption. But then you also say:

```
self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
if let message: AnyObject = error!.userInfo!["error"] {
    self.message.text = "\(message)"
}
```

Here you have *no* `dispatch_async` onto the main thread - so if you are doing this on a background thread, those lines are illegal and Bad Things can happen.

Comment: what would you suggest i do?